# CakePHP 3.8. Security Component - FormHelper end() method

Tags: cakephp-3.0, form-helpers

**Exact Problem and the Solution**

Upon activating the CakePHP (3) Security Component, when loading a form, you generate three hidden fields in the form. These are '_Token[fields]', '_Token[unlocked]' and '_Token[debug]'. What exactly happens is the Form->end() method calls the secure() method (see FormHelper) when the request data contains a ['Token'] parameter.

The forms that were not working for me were all forms rendered as an Element. For these forms, the '$this->request->params' did not contain the parameter normally generated by the Security Component.

Solution was in manually adding the parameter to the request data..

```
$this->request->params['_Token'] = ['unlockedFields' => []];
```

This than runs through the secure() method of FormHelper, as it should, and token parameters are correctly added.

**Original Question**

I have an issue using the SecurityComponent of CakePHP 3.8.

Everything was working fine, until I loaded Component in my AppController.

```
If (!$this->request->is('ajax')) {

    $this->loadComponent('Security');

}
```

My forms were working fine, but upon activating the component I get an error message. Apparently using the Security Component checks for an additional token apart from the csrf-token.

```
'_Token' was not found in request data.
```

I found a solution in customizing the Form->end() method.

> "The end() method closes and completes a form. Often, end() will only
>   output a closing form tag, but using end() is a good practice as it
>   enables FormHelper to insert the hidden form elements that
>   Cake\Controller\Component\SecurityComponent requires."

I customized my end method as suggested in documentation:

```
echo $this->Form->end(['data-type' => 'hidden']);
```

But my output in HTML differs from the output in the documentation..

Documentation Output:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_Token[fields]" data-type="hidden"
        value="2981c38990f3f6ba935e6561dc77277966fabd6d%3AAddresses.id">
    <input type="hidden" name="_Token[unlocked]" data-type="hidden"
        value="address%7Cfirst_name">
</div>
```

Example of a non-working form..

```
    echo $this->Form->create($athlete, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Athletesux', 'action' => $action]]);
    echo $this->Form->control('user_id', ['type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $userid]);
    echo $this->Form->control('first_name');
    echo $this->Form->control('last_name');
    echo $this->Form->control('threek_time', ['value' => $athlete['3K_time']]); 
    echo $this->Form->control('fivek_time', ['value' => $athlete['5K_time']]);     
    echo $this->Form->control('tenk_time', ['value' => $athlete['10K_time']]); 
    echo $this->Form->select('country', $countryoptions);  
    echo $this->Form->select('gender', $gender);   
    echo $this->Form->button('Add Athlete');
    echo $this->Form->end();
```

My output contains only one hidden field, for '_csrfToken'...

Can anyone explain what I can do about this? I don't find much information on this..

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use `$this->Form->create` to start the form, or a manual `<form>` tag?

Comment: Yes I did. The problem is that the fields "_Token[fields]", "_Token[unlocked]" and "_Token[debug]" are not added to the form. They should be added through the "        $this->Security->generateToken($this->request);" method, but no idea how exactly..

Comment: And you're using `$this->Form->input` or `$this->Form->control` to add the form fields?

Comment: Example of a non-working form added to question..

Comment: This looks very much like many of my forms, and mine get the fields added automatically with no problem. In the `end` function of the HTML helper, there's an `if` block that executes and is responsible for generating this. Check whether that block is being executed. If so, why is there no output from it; if not, which condition is failing?

Comment: You mean FormHelper I suppose?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Sorry.

Comment: In CakePHP 3.8 I find it in the secure() method of the FormHelper class. But unsure how to use it.. "Generates a hidden field with a security hash based on the fields used in the form. If $secureAttributes is set, these HTML attributes will be merged into the hidden input tags generated for the Security Component. This is especially useful to set HTML5 attributes like 'form'."

Comment: The `secure` method should be called automatically by the `end` method. I'm looking at 3.8 as well.

Comment: I just checked a few more forms, and apparently it does work on normal forms. The forms I tested are all generated on Elements that are rendered through ajax call.. These are blocking.. I know you should not use Security Component on ajax calls. But is this also true for forms generated through ajax call?

Comment: And if not, doesn't it create a security risk?

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere. :-) It only adds those fields if `$this->_View->getRequest()->getParam('_Token')` is set. Which happens in the `generateToken` function of the security component. Seems for your other related question that you have this disabled on Ajax calls now. Maybe it needs to be more selectively disabled?

Comment: Hello Greg, I found the solution in manually adding the parameter before rendering the form.. It then runs through the secure() method in FormHelper and adds the needed hidden parameters. Thank you for your help!